# ER=EPR and information fuelling cosmic expansion

Tags: expansion, supermassive-black-hole, dark-energy

I apologize in advance for the lack of education, I'm a Canadian hillbilly.

I was considering the concepts of ER=EPR and the growth of the black hole's internal system with the addition of information going into it. I was also considering the concepts of Page time and the outgoing radiation of the black hole.

Question:
Could the expansion of spacetime be the result of 2 entangles systems forming causal boundaries with one another? That when theres a distance great enough that a causal boundary is achieved, the entanglement just transitions its information out in the form of expanding space time? There should be observable tests that one could do to check it, I would think, but then again I huffed gas as a child.

So, again, I apologize for the strange and uneducated comment, but I'm curios in the relation to spacetime and the entanglement of outgoing black hole radiation after the page time, if there is indeed a relation. I feel like they are related -- and I understand I'm breaking all the standards of scientific rigour, but I can't stress enough how mentally diminished I am.

Anyway, any input on this beside the obvious fact that I'm doing nothing but speculating?

Thank you!

Comment: *Welcome to Stack Exchange!* Readers here have a variety of backgrounds. For people like myself, could you at least briefly explain what "ER=EPR" means? Perhaps add a few links? *Thanks!*

Answer (score 2):

It is a very possible interesting possibility. In fact this is already accounted for in a theory, and this hypothesis adds more to it.

So Quantum entanglement could form casual boundries, according to ER=EPR hypothesis, it is very well possible that it could escape outside the event horizon, because it is a major factor in hawking radiation

When Astronomers observed large elliptic galaxies, they found unusual discrepancies in mass via mergers and accretion, so there must exist an extra source of mass. This was predicted to be dark energy.

The theory that the black hole has vacuum energy that forms the basis of the cosmological constant, this theory is known as cosmological coupling.

So the vacuum energy in the Interstellar medium could be sucked in the black hole, and then later be released back into space via hawking radiation however one crucial factor for hawking radiation is quantum entanglement, which may escape the event horizon posed by ER=EPR hypothesis , which can escape the causal boundary and this quantum entanglement may teleport some entangled particle which contains the microscopic force known as the Casimir effect which is a candidate for dark energy, technically fueling the cosmological constant.

Now, to be honest, I am also speculating, there is no way to find it out, unless and until we have a concrete theory of Quantum Gravity.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your input! I suppose I should follow up with other questions within this same topic, as they’ve been stewing away in my mind for a while. Again, thank you for the reply— it’ll give me something to think on.

Comment: @ChristainJP You're welcome!